# If an application has XHR calls with application/json as the 'type' does it mean it's AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Please forgive my ignorance in this as I am just learning this.  I am interested in using a solution for my website where once I embed a javascript code, the code will make api calls to show images.  What I need to know if if that javascript will be using ajax to show the images.

I had the console open in Chrome and looked at the XHR tab when all the images came in I see that the 'Type' for these image requests is set to 'application/json'.  Does that mean this JavaScript is using AJAX to show these photos?

Comment: If its an API call, odds are it is an application/json call, and is indeed an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

It may help if you post source code. It sounds like your javascript is (or should be) making AJAX calls to the API, which returns data that can be processed as an Image().

Comment: I don't have permission to post code as it is given to us because of a signed agreement.  That sucks.  Is there any way I can check? If i am not wrong if the api call shows up in XHR, isnt' it safe to assume it's AJAX?